# Javascript exception when opening window for the second time

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radwindow

I'm performing CRUD operations on a TelerikRadWindow, which works fine at the first time but when i try to do it a second time throws Javascript exception "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'show') at openRadWindow". Any ideas on what it could be? Thank you in advance!

```
<div class="form" runat="server" id="divUC" >
<telerik:RadWindowManager RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="radInfoWindow" runat="server" DestroyOnClose="true" CommandName="Confirmar" ShowContentDuringLoad="false" language="pt-PT">             
                <Windows>
                    <telerik:RadWindow RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="UserListDialog" runat="server" Title="Editar Timesheets" Height="400px"
                        Width="800px" Left="150px" ReloadOnShow="true" ShowContentDuringLoad="false" 
                        Modal="true" DestroyOnClose="true" VisibleStatusbar="False"
                        Behaviors="Close,Move,Resize" CssClass="opaque"  KeepInScreenBounds="True" AutoSize="false" 
                    >
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <uc1:ViewEmissaoTimeSheetEdit ID="EditTimesheet" runat="server"  />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </telerik:RadWindow>
                </Windows>
            </telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

//JS function

```
function openRadWindow() {
        var radwindow = $find('<%=UserListDialog.ClientID %>');
       radwindow.show();
    }
```

//Form opening

```
(e.CommandName == "InitInsert") //Same for Edit
        {

            try
            {
                //UserListDialog.Dispose(); 

                string script = "function f(){openRadWindow(); Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}Sys.Application.add_load(f);";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", script, true); //Open Window
            
                e.Canceled = true;

 (...) some other code to deal with creating and binding the form
                
            }
```

Comment: looks like you're trying to find server-side code from the client side.... maybe use $('#UserListDialog')

Comment: Thank you @pcalkins. Unfortunatelly that is not the problem, doing it server side the window don't open. Client works fine at first try, but on second crashes. For sure something is missing me, but don't know what

Comment: yeah, I think I misunderstood... looks like you're generating the JS server-side?  Not sure why it's working the 1st time and not the 2nd... but you might want to avoid $find there... just use $('#<%=UserListDialog.ClientID %>').show();  ?  Also make sure to wait for load... so $( document ).ready(function() { $('#<%=UserListDialog.ClientID %>').show(); });

Comment: Or short-hand for onload: $(function() {...

Comment: Unfortunately that didin't change the behaviour

Comment: maybe include the code/markup that calls the openRadWindow() function in your post.... could be a problem with the event handler

Comment: @pcalkins. Sorry, i didn't believe the problem was there, so i din't shared it right awaw. Edited the question. What do you think?

Comment: I think it's a timing issue... looks like a mix of ajax vs non-ajax methods?  Maybe check this page: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/executing-javascript-function-from-server-side-code

Comment: @pcalkins: I'm getting the same error, and the reason why we're using $find is because our control is for a library and inherits from CompositeControl, it's not a aspx or ascx that can mix markup and embedded code.  I think it's a timing issue, thinking of seeing if we can just introduce a slight delay on loading to fix the problem or put in a more complex dom loaded test.